# Questions regarding mysql and java

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm stuck on a couple of problems, and i've tried googlein, but to no sucsess.. i'm a starter in android development, and i've decided to make a pretty big app but useless, this is only training.

But i'm stuck on a couple of things. i wish to connect to mysql database(i know how to do this), and from there get some information and save them to strings. For starters i want to get some names and i wish to save them to a strings. i wish to get 100 names, and i wanna save them to a1, a2, a3, etc. i use the following mysql command

> ("SELECT users.id, users.displayname, users.gender, picture.user_id FROM users, picture WHERE users.id=picture.user_id ORDER BY picture.finalsum LIMIT 100")

how would i go about getting the displayname saved to the variable(s).

also how do i store bytearray in my database?

how would i go about getting images from my database into a listview? only pictures no text.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try a tutorial like this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: I think you should focus on asking one question at a time. How to show images in a ListView has nothing to do with MySQL or databases.

Comment: For JDBC, you can check many of the available tutorials on the Internet (just Google `jdbc mysql tutorial`).